# Developing WPS Client using ZOO Project

Tags: wpsclient, zoo-project

By following the [ZOO Client Documentation](http://zoo-project.org/docs/client/index.html), I have set up the zoo-client-demo folder to be accessible to localhost. I have also set up the assets folder and its subfolders to contain the required js and mustache files.

The problem is, I also need an HTML file to be present somewhere so that the client actually displays something when the appropriate URL is entered into the browser.

The only bit of HTML code in the documentation is the following:

> Before using the ZOO-Client, you will first have to include the javascript files from your web page. With the use of requirejs you will need only one line in your HTML page to include everything at once. This line will look like the following:

`<script data-main="assets/js/first" src="assets/js/lib/require.js"></script>`

1) Can someone please explain what this line means?
2) Is the above line enough, or do I need some more code (both the HTML and the .js files)?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [page](http://www.zoo-project.org/examples/spatialtools.html%20page) for sample usage of the ZOO-Client, you will need some HTML and Javascript code too.